# Accessing Python datastructure

Tags: python, loops, data-structures

In my Flask application, I receive the following data structure:

```py
{"privMap":{"privKeys":["it","de"],"privValues":["Ciao","Hallo"]}}
```

which is sent by a JavaScript code (where I can access single pairs for example with `translations.get('it');`). How can I loop through this data structure in Python?

Comment: Sure. Thank you for asking. It was a structure I have never handled before in Python. But having seen the answer of Pouya, I should have come to the solution myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip()` to pair two lists and get tuples.

```
data  ={"privMap":{"privKeys":["it","de"],"privValues":["Ciao","Hallo"]}}

privKeys = data['privMap']['privKeys']
privValues = data['privMap']['privValues']

for item in zip(privKeys, privValues):
    print(item)
```

And this is the result:

```
('it', 'Ciao')
('de', 'Hallo')
```